# Control audio quality for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am streaming online radio from url using MediaPlayer.
Is there any way to increase/decrease audio quality in any way?
The idea of the client is to have better quality for the paid version of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Android sdk is a sample titled API Demos. There is a great graphical eq in there.  I haven't implemented it yet, but I am planning to test in  my app soon.